# Adding the ability to search a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a long listview so I'm trying to add a search bar so I don't have to scroll through the listview to find what I want. It seems to filter out which ever ones it wants to, any clue as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the list:

```
public class ExList {

private List<Example> listExample = new ArrayList<Example>();

public void populateThingsList(){
        listExample.add(new Example("asdf name", 1, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.1_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("ghkj name", 2, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.2_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("astg name", 3, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.3_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("ghky name", 4, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.4_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("ghee name", 5, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.5_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("asre name", 6, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.6_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("yuoi name6", 7, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.7_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("oiuy name", 8, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.8_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("fdsa name", 9, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.9_icon, "Example detail 3"));
        listExample.add(new Example("lkjh name", 10, "Example detail 1", "Example detail 2", R.drawable.10_icon, "Example detail 3"));
}
```

and the method I wrote for searching:

```
public void filter(String search) {
        Example ex;
        String s = search.trim().toLowerCase();
        String t;

        for (int i = 0; i < listExample.size(); i++) {
            ex = listExample.get(i);
            t = ex.getName().trim().toLowerCase();
            if (!t.contains(s)){
                listExample.remove(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

and the code for when the text in the get's changed

```
searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
            if (!searchText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                listExample = exList.getListExample();
                exList.filter(searchText.getText().toString());
                populateListView();
            }
            if (searchText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                listExample = exList.getListExample();
                populateListView();
                //this resets the listview and actually works
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

my arrayadapter class and populatelistview method

```
private void populateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Example> adapter = new MyListAdapter();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exampleListView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Example> {
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, listExample);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null) {
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
            }
            Example currentExample = listExample.get(position);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(currentExample.getIconId());

            TextView detailThreeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtDThree);
            detailThreeText.setText(currentExample.getDThree());

            TextView detailTwoText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtDTwo);
            detailTwoText.setText(currentExample.getDTwo());

            TextView detailOneText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtDOne);
            detailOneText.setText(currentExample.getDOne());

            TextView nameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtName);
            nameText.setText(currentExample.getName());



            return itemView;
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by:  It seems to filter out which ever ones it wants to?

Comment: would autocomplete listView be helpful in your situation ?

Comment: I don't want the searchbar to auto complete.

Comment: What I mean by filters out whatever it wants is let's just say I type ghk into the EditText, instead of only showing the examples "ghky name" and "ghkj name" it'll show a few others that don't have ghk in the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to write some generic code here, modify it and let me know.  Don't use a separate function to compare, do it inside `onTextChanged`

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String searchString = searchText.getText().toString();
                    int textLength = searchString.length();

                    ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>;
                    //searchList.clear(); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < listExample.size(); i++) {
                        Example model = listExample.get(i);
                        String Names = model.getName().toString();
                        if (textLength <= Names.length()) {
                            // compare the String in EditText with Names in the
                            // ArrayList
                            if (searchString.equalsIgnoreCase(Names.substring(
                                    0, textLength)))
                                searchList.add(listExample.get(i));
                        }
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<Example> ad = new YOUR_ADAPTER(
                            YOUR_CLASS.this, searchList);
                    YOUR_LISTVIEW.setAdapter(ad);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: searchList.add(listExample.get(i)); doesn't work because searchlist is an ArrayList of strings and I want more than just strings in my listview. I'll try to play around with this though, if I post my arrayadapter could you help a little more?

Comment: Yeah, I will only if you're going to accept and up vote if my answer helps you :D

Comment: Try changing `ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>;` to `List<Example> searchList = new ArrayList<Example>;`

Comment: I added the code for the ArrayAdapter and I'll gladly up vote your answer if you can help.

Comment: I changed ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>; to List<Example> searchList = new ArrayList<Example>; and changed ArrayAdapter<Example> ad = new YOUR_ADAPTER(YOUR_CLASS.this, searchList);YOUR_LISTVIEW.setAdapter(ad); to listExample = searchList; populateListView(); and it worked great.

Comment: I accepted your answer but I don't have a high enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: That's alright :). Glad it helped you. Happy coding and thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

In all seriousness, you're doing something wrong. The fastest way to figure out what's wrong is to debug the app, stepping through it with breakpoints. At each breakpoint, check the values of the important values. At some point, you'll find that your assumptions are incorrect. For example, you'll find that a comparison operation isn't working correctly.

Trust me, this is the fastest way to solve the problem. The rest of us here could read over your code for hours, trying to find the bug, but by debugging you can probably find the problem in minutes.